# O(m+n)-time algorithm for a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have just started learning about graphs, and can't seem to be able to come up with an algorithm for this question, and don't even know where to start. I would really appreciate your help!

*For a given connected graph G=(V,E), design an O(n+m)-time algorithm to find a node v∈V so removing v and all its adjacent edges will not disconnect G.*

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Perform a breadth first search of the graph. The last node found can be removed without disconnecting the graph.

Proof: the BFS produces a spanning tree of the graph, and the last node found is always a leaf of that tree. Removing the leaf of a spanning tree does not disconnect the tree, and leaves a spanning tree of the remaining vertices.

Comment: This is only a partial solution - there can be articulation points further up the BFS tree where removing that articulation point will disconnect the sub-trees rooted at that vertex from the main body of the tree.

Comment: @MT0 I'm not quite sure what you mean. Did you misread the question as "will disconnect G" rather than "will not disconnect G"?

Comment: If you find all the articulation points then any that are not articulation points will be part of a biconnected component and will not disconnect the graph if they are removed. Performing a BFS and taking the leaves will not find all the non-articulation points in the graph.

Comment: Sure, but the question is to find a single non-articulation point. Agreed that finding them all is more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

A vertex can be removed (without disconnecting the rest of the graph) if:

1. It is not an articulation point; or
2. It terminates a path within the graph where that path is only connected at one end; or
3. It is the only vertex in the graph.

See [Hopcroft, J.; Tarjan, R. (1973). "Algorithm 447: efficient algorithms for graph manipulation". Communications of the ACM. 16 (6): 372–378](https://dx.doi.org/10.1145%2F362248.362272) for an algorithm to identify articulation points:

Perform a depth-first search on the graph - below is some pseudo-code for a recursive DFS algorithm:

```
procedure RecursiveDFS ( u ) {
  mark u as visited
  u.index = u.lowPoint = ++global_index
  if (   ( u is the root and has zero connected edges )
      or ( u is not the root and has one connected edge ) ) {
    mark u as a leaf
  }
  for each ( edge e connected to u ) {
    if ( e is unvisited ) {
      mark e as visited
      let e = {u , v}
      if ( v is unvisited ) {
        mark e as tree edge
        RecursiveDFS ( v )
        if ( v.lowPoint < u.lowPoint )
        {
          u.lowPoint = v.index
        } else {
          mark u as an articulation-point
        }
      } else {
        mark e as cotree edge
        if ( v.index < u.lowPoint )
        {
          u.lowPoint = v.index
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will visit each vertex and each edge once `O(m+n)` and will mark vertices as articulation points if at a given vertex there exists a sub-tree of the DFS rooted at that vertex which has no co-tree (back) edges emanating from the sub-tree connecting to an ancestor of that given vertex.

The special case is the root vertex (where you started the DFS) which will always be marked as an articulation point (since it has no ancestors for the sub-tree to connect to) - instead you should check whether the root vertex has only one adjacent tree edge and one or more adjacent co-tree (back) edges (and is part of a biconnected component).

Vertices that terminate a path will either be:

1. A leaf vertex of the DFS tree (with exactly one connected tree edge, from the parent within the DFS tree, and zero connected co-tree edges); or
2. The root vertex of the DFS tree one adjacent tree edge and zero adjacent co-tree (back) edges.